# Type Comparison Performance: TryCast vs GetType

Tags: c#

What I'm wondering is what would be the best performance for determining what child class was actually passed into the function.

Here are the 3 different ways I am going between for what would be the best performance:
  (ACHData, CCData, and DC Data all Inherit from BaseData)

```
public BaseProcessor GetProcessor(BaseData paymentInfo)
{
    if (paymentInfo.GetType() == typeof(ACHData))
    {
        return GetACHProcessor((ACHData)paymentInfo);
    }
    else if (paymentInfo.GetType() == typeof(CCData))
    {
        return GetCCProcessor((CCData)paymentInfo);
    }
    else if (paymentInfo.GetType() == typeof(DCData))
    {
        return GetDCProcessor((DCData)paymentInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(ExceptionMessage);
    }
}

public BaseProcessor GetProcessor(BaseData paymentInfo)
{
    if (paymentInfo is ACHData)
    {
        return GetACHProcessor((ACHData)paymentInfo);
    }
    else if (paymentInfo is CCData)
    {
        return GetCCProcessor((CCData)paymentInfo);
    }
    else if (paymentInfo is DCData)
    {
        return GetDCProcessor((DCData)paymentInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(ExceptionMessage);
    }
}

public BaseProcessor GetProcessor(BaseData paymentInfo)
{
    var achInfo = paymentInfo as ACHData;
    if (achInfo != null)
    {
        return GetACHProcessor(achInfo);
    }

    var ccInfo = paymentInfo as CCData;
    if (ccInfo != null)
    {
        return GetCCProcessor(ccInfo);
    }

    var dcInfo = paymentInfo as DCData;
    if (dcInfo != null)
    {
        return GetDCProcessor(dcInfo);
    }

    throw new Exception(ExceptionMessage);
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling we're about to see a lot of "you need to benchmark it!" comments/answers. Seriously, only you can run the benchmarks.

Comment: There's no point letting your method take a baseclass when all you do is check its type and upcast it inside the method. You should revisit your design and take some polymorphism/generics into account.

Comment: I agree with Jeroen Vannevel that you should rework your design.  However, I would add that if you absolutely must use this approach, the best performance would probably be had by creating a "ProcessorType" and a corresponding abstract property on the base class.  Then you can use a switch block in your GetProcessor method.  This pattern is used, for example, by System.Linq.Expressions.Expression and its subclasses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would re-think your entire design. Have your classes implement an interface that forces them to choose what to provide as a processor:

```
public interface IKnowWhatProcessorIWant {
    IProcessor CreateProcessor();
}

public class ACHData : BaseData, IKnowWhatProcessorIWant {
    public IProcessor CreateProcessor() {
        return new GetACHProcessor(this);
    }
}
```

Then your `GetProcessor` code becomes:

```
public BaseProcessor GetProcessor(IKnowWhatProcessorIWant obj) {
    return obj.CreateProcessor();
}
```

...or, you could omit that method entirely then.

Comment: The problem with doing the above is that this is my Factory class. At this point, I don't know what processor I want which is why I have this method. I want to be able to code a "DoSale" method that collects the payment information, and then just does 

    var sale = ProcessorFactory.GetProcessor(paymentInfo); sale.Credit();

Comment: The entire point of this is to remove the need for the factory. Your objects decide for themselves what processor they want.

Comment: After looking at it a bit more, I understand what you're trying to get at. I didn't exactly go with an interface, but I was able to just use an abstract class and achieved the same thing. Now I don't have to do any type comparisons at all. Thank you for the enlightenment!

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help :)